# How to create output files with fixed number of lines in hadoop/map reduce?

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce

Let's say we have N input files with different number of lines. We need to generate output files such the each output file has exactly K number of lines (except the last one which can have < K records).

- Is it possible to do this using single MR job?
- We should open the files for writing explicitly in reducer.
- The records in output should be shuffled.

thanks,
Paramesh

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that the input file has 990 records which have to be split into 9 files of 100 records each and the last file of 90 records. A total of 10 files

Use the [NLineInputFormat](https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r1.2.1/api/org/apache/hadoop/mapred/lib/NLineInputFormat.html) and set the `mapred.line.input.format.linespermap` to 100. This way each mapper will process 100 lines from the input data set. Set the number of reducers to 10, which is the number of output files.

In the mapper emit Key between 1 and 10 (which is the number of output files) and emit the value as the input record. Make sure that the keys emitted by mappers are balanced between 1 and 10 and not skewed.

Comment: When keys are equally distributed the first n-1 files may not be filled before moving to overflow file. Also, this needs 2 passes. First one to count the number of lines in all input files and second pass during MR. Is it possible to do in one pass?

Answer (score 0):

A different approach is to have a single reducer and use the multipleoutputformat to generate multiple outputfiles.
In that reducer you can simply have a counter and change the output file name when needed.

Comment: just to add a single reducer might be a bottle neck when the data is huge as in the case of big data

Comment: Correct. Yet using NLineInputFormat makes assumptions about the input. It's a choice that can fall either way depending on the situation at hand.